# Segmentation fault (core dumped) issue

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read in input from a user, and then tokenize each word and put each word into an array of strings. At the end, the contents of the array are printed out for debugging. My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

  int MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 200;
  volatile int running = 1;
  while(running) {

    char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
    char tokens[100];

    printf("shell> ");
    fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE, stdin);

    //tokenize input string, put each token into an array
    char *space;
    space = strtok(input, " ");
    tokens[0] = space;

    int i = 1;
    while (space != NULL) {
      space = strtok(NULL, " ");
      tokens[i] = space;
      ++i;
    }

    for(i = 0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++) {
      printf(tokens[i]);
      printf("\n");
    }

  printf("\n");     //clear any extra spaces

  //return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

After I type in my input at the "shell> " prompt, gcc gives me the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any idea as to why this error is happening? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace at the point of the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char tokens[100];
```

This declaration should be array of array of characters(two dimensional character array) to hold  Multiple strings

```
  char tokens[100][30];   
  //in your case this wont work because you require pointers   
  //while dealing with  `strtok()`
```

**USE**

Array of character pointers

```
char *tokens[100];
```

---

This is also wrong

```
printf(tokens[i]);
```

You should use printf with format specifier %s while printing string.
change like this

```
printf("%s", tokens[i]);
```

Comment: Your first version (array of strings) won't work -- look at the `while (space != NULL)` loop.  It has to be an array of pointers.

Comment: Changing it to `char tokens[100][30]` creates the error `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[30]’ from type ‘char *’`.

Comment: please use this **char *tokens[100];**

Comment: @flexcalibur6 you have to declare as `char* tokens[100] = {NULL};`, notice last loop too

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan what are you pointing out in the last loop, exactly?

Comment: @flexcalibur6 Either declare as `char *tokens[100];` and simplify while loop just as `while(tokens[++i] = strtok(NULL, " "));`. Give it a try!...my point is `tokens[i]` should be NULL  terminated according to last loop.